Error: there is no registered task type 'karate'. Did you miss installing an extension that provides a corresponding task provider?
Qué tal? Estoy haciendo un curso de pruebas automatizadas con Karate framework. Las pruebas las estoy corriendo en VS Code y cada vez que quiero correr las pruebas individuales me salta este error:
Error: there is no registered task type 'karate'. Did you miss installing an extension that provides a corresponding task provider?

En la consola me muestra en rojo la siguiente linea
Executing task: mvn clean test-compile -f "<directorio del proyecto>\myproject\pom.xml" exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.intuit.karate.cli.Main" -Dexec.args="<driectorio del proyecto>\feature\HomePage.feature:18" -Dexec.classpathScope="test" 

Y aparentemente el error es el siguiente:
[com.intuit.karate.cli.Main.main()] INFO  com.intuit.karate - Karate version: 1.4.1
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 69:

Le di muchas vueltas pero no tengo idea de como solucionarlo. De pronto, ¿alguien me puede dar una mano?
